# Post to URL after authenticating with Firebase

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am wondering if there is a way to post a auth token to my own server after a user has authenticated with firebase with email and password. I would like to store some information in a secondary database on my server that they can only get access to if they have authenticated with Firebase. Is this possible?

Comment: It sure is. What language are you using? Did you try anything yet? If so, please add the code of what you tried to your question by clicking the little [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35188598/edit) link under it.

Comment: I have not tried anything but I am using node.js for my server and an ionic app for the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html
```

you can hook to `onauth` event client-side, grab the information you need and send it to the client.

Doing this without the 'help' of a client (i.e. firebase automatically somehow notifying your server about new user / new login), is not supported (sadly).

EDIT: If you don't believe `uid`s  to be secure enough (and security is the concern), here is the way how to achieve the same thing securely:

- create collection 'onauth-events'. Every time client receives `onauth` callback, they push to onauth-events some object with whatever information is necessary
- you can easily set up the validation rule such that `uid` present in the object that is being pushed to `onauth_events` must match the real `uid` of the user
- your server can listen on `child_added` events on the onauth-events collection and react accordingly.

Comment: I am concerned that this method has potential security issues. If the client receives the uid and token and sends those to the server to be used as auth whats stopping them from getting anyones uid and setting their token to "bobTheBuilder" then messing with their info? Is there a way to make this more secure?

Comment: You're right, I'm not sure how much are those uids unguessable. Anyways, I edited post with another approach you can use.

Answer (score 0):

See the link below as a reference:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#java

Set up a cloud function in Firebase that includes your desired code (in your case the cloud function would be written to act as a proxy between your app and secondary database).

Before invoking the code from your app that triggers the cloud function, set some parameters in the data being passed to the cloud function regarding the user:

```
// Message text passed from the client.
const text = data.text;
// Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
const uid = context.auth.uid;
const name = context.auth.token.name || null;
const picture = context.auth.token.picture || null;
const email = context.auth.token.email || null;
```

If the user is not authenticated in your app, the data sent to the cloud function will have the data pertaining to the user set to null. Then, in your cloud function, you can check if the user was authenticated (see code immediately below). At this point, you could pass the data originally from your app through the cloud function into your secondary database.

```
// Checking attribute.
if (!(typeof text === 'string') || text.length === 0) {
  // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
      'one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.');
}
// Checking that the user is authenticated.
if (!context.auth) {
  // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
      'while authenticated.');
}
```